# How do I add a custom item to the top of a dropdown using the asp.net mvc Html.DropDownList helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list on my asp.net mvc site:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("CustCodes") %>
```

My controller:

```
 ICallService sc = new CallService();
 IList<CustCode> custCodes = sc.GetCustCodes();
 ViewData["CustCodes"] = new SelectList(custCodes, "ID", "Name");
```

What I want is once the dropdown is displayed to either have a blank entry at the top or an option that says "Select a Customer".  Do I need to use jquery to do this or is there something built into the DropDowList helper that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an override that contains an option label.

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("CustCodes",
                       ViewData["CustCodes"] as SelectList,
                       "Select a Customer",
                       null ) %>
```